# Comparsion b/w Two Array and then logical OR operation at other function (GNU bash 4.2 version)

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix

I am new to unix and learning it basics. I wanted to compare same index of two different arrays and on the basis of comparision I wanted to put a data to other array. First I tried to use it with string type array , I was unsucessful then I tried to use it with numeric array again I failed so I decided to discuss I tried multiple combinations of OR statements and also has passed index by index array elements as a parameter but still not working. I only wanted to do at other function not at same function.

```
Problem Description
1) suppose if at binary_data_1[0]=0 
  and binary_data_2[0]=1
  then at master_binary_data[0]=0
  means compare the binary_data_1 or binary_data_2 for same index and if
  any element is 0 it will insert the value 0 for that index for master_binary_data[ ] array

  2) suppose if at string_array[0]='A'
     and string_array2[0]='B'
     then at master_string_array[0]='A'
     means if any record is 'A' at any index master_string_array[] for that index should 
     be 'A'



Now suppose my arrays in the function1

  #as 
  loopcount1=0
  function1()
  {
  binary_data_1=(0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0)
  binary_data_2=(1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0)
  string_array=( 'A' 'B' 'A' 'A' 'B' 'A' )
  string_array2=( 'B' 'A' 'B' 'A' 'B' 'B' )
  }
  #at by using the function2 I wanted to achive the same
  function2()
  {
  # 
  # I tried if [  "${binary_data_1[$loopcount1]}" -eq 0 ]  || [ "${binary_data_2[$loopcount1]}" -eq 0 ] | bash -x
  # then
  # master_binary_data[$loopcount1]=0
  # I tried if [  "${string_array[$loopcount1]}" == 'A' ]  || [ "${string_array[$loopcount1]}" == 'A' ] | bash -x
  # master_string_array[$loopcount1]=A
  }
  ### Also passed each elements of array as a parameter but still not works


EDITED CODE 

lopcount1=0
set -A binary_data_1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
set -A binary_data_2 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
set -A string_array  'A' 'B' 'A' 'A' 'B' 'A'
set -A string_array2 'B' 'A' 'B' 'A' 'B' 'B'
echo "${string_array[@]}"
echo "${string_array2[@]}"
echo "${binary_data_1[@]}"
echo "${binary_data_2[@]}"
echo " Function 2 called "
function2 
#at by using the function2 I wanted to achive the same
function2()
{
if [  "${binary_data_1[$loopcount1]}" -eq 0 ]  || [ "${binary_data_2[$loopcount1]}" -eq 0 ] 
then
   master_binary_data[$loopcount1]=0
fi
if [  "${string_array[$loopcount1]}" == 'A' ]  || [ "${string_array2[$loopcount1]}" == 'A' ] 
then
    master_string_array[$loopcount1]=A
fi
loopcount1=`expr loopcount1+1`
}
echo "${master_string_array[@]}"
echo "${master_binary_data[@]}"
echo "Function 2 ends here "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your arrays globally and then use them inside your function2.
The below piece of code will do it

```
#!/bin/bash
lopcount1=0
binary_data_1=(0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0)
binary_data_2=(1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0)
string_array=( 'A' 'B' 'A' 'A' 'B' 'A' )
string_array2=( 'B' 'A' 'B' 'A' 'B' 'B' )
#at by using the function2 I wanted to achive the same
function2()
{

if [  "${binary_data_1[$loopcount1]}" -eq 0 ]  || [ "${binary_data_2[$loopcount1]}" -eq 0 ] | bash -x
then
   master_binary_data[$loopcount1]=0
fi
if [  "${string_array[$loopcount1]}" == 'A' ]  || [ "${string_array[$loopcount1]}" == 'A' ] | bash -x
then
    master_string_array[$loopcount1]=A
fi
}
```

MODIFIED

```
#!/bin/bash
 loopcount1=0
 binary_data_1=(0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 )
 binary_data_2=(1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0)
 string_array=('A' 'B' 'A' 'A' 'B' 'A')
 string_array2=('B' 'A' 'B' 'A' 'B' 'B')
echo "${string_array[@]}"
echo "${string_array2[@]}"
echo "${binary_data_1[@]}"
echo "${binary_data_2[@]}"
echo " Function 2 called "
#at by using the function2 I wanted to achive the same
function2()
{
if [ "${binary_data_1[$loopcount1]}" -eq 0 ]  || [ "${binary_data_2[$loopcount1]}" -eq 0 ]
then
   master_binary_data[$loopcount1]=0
fi
if [ "${string_array[$loopcount1]}" == 'A' ]  || [ "${string_array2[$loopcount1]}" == 'A' ]
then
    master_string_array[$loopcount1]=A
fi
loopcount1=`expr loopcount1+1`
}
function2
echo "${master_string_array[@]}"
echo "${master_binary_data[@]}"
echo "Function 2 ends here "
```

Comment: at Unix any element can be a array so if I have declared an element only then make that element as array in the function and consume that in the other function is that possible?

Comment: its possible you need to pass the array as argument to another function for e.g. _function2 binary_data_1 binary_data_2_ and then use these argument inside function2 like below -                                                                   **$1 corresponds to first array and $2 corresponds to second array**

Comment: then at the function2 suppose a array contains 10 elements then how to fetch those 10 elements using $1 is we have to take another array means ARRAY[ ]=$1 I have already tried this but not working if possible please modify it in your answer

Comment: I will accept but there is one problem I just running your answer with modification set -A binary_data_1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
set -A binary_data_2 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
set -A string_array  'A' 'B' 'A' 'A' 'B' 'A'
set -A string_array2 'B' 'A' 'B' 'A' 'B' 'B'
echo "${string_array[@]}"
echo "${string_array2[@]}"
echo "${binary_data_1[@]}"
echo "${binary_data_2[@]}" and calling function2  but A B A A B A
B A B A B B
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
 Function 2 called 
lastexp.ksh[12]: function2:  not found.


Function 2 ends here  it not works showing output like this.

Comment: there is an error on the code that function2 not found.

Comment: you can access whole array inside another element using below syntax                     **declare -a temp_array=("${!1}")**                                                             you have to pass the array as argument like below                                                      **function2 binary_data_1[@]**

Comment: can you please provide modified code which is throwing error, I am not able to understand anything as out of that comment as it is very clumsy

Comment: please see my question at bottom I have appended my code under EDITED heading

Comment: it is showing error like today.ksh[7]: temp_array="${!1}": 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.
today.ksh[8]: "${temp_array{@}}": 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.

Comment: You need to call function2 at the end you are calling it before its definition thats why it is not working. I am posting modified code in my answer for your reference under **MODIFIED** tag